# Open app at specified page with Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am looking for a way to open an app on the page a pushnotification is pointing to.
Is there a way to see if I have received any push notification when starting my app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for the launch option keys `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` and `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` in the launchOptions-Dictionary given in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: I have found this one. NSString *params=[[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] objectForKey:@"key"]; but I don't know what kind of key I should use

Comment: Do NSLog(@"%@", launchOptions) to see the contents of the whole dictionary in the console including all keys.