# iOS : Can I start my application with device restart using push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to automatically start my application when device restarts? Can we use push notification to invoke the application when device restarts?

Comment: Somebody please reply

Comment: My app is not VOIP-enabled app

Answer (score 2):

For your first question no it is not possible without JailBreak, you cannot open app without user interaction, although there is an exception for **VOIP-enabled** app.

more info: [Can iPhone apps start on start-up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300815/can-iphone-apps-start-on-start-up)

For second question yes you can open app with push notification.

more info: [Open app at specified page with Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615412/open-app-at-specified-page-with-push-notification)

**Edit:**

You can get the payload from launchOptions as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary* payload = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (payload) {
        // process the payload here
    }
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can you explain more about how to set value to UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey in launch options? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UIBackgroundModes section in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) - it seems to state that adding the `voip` key *will* autostart an app on boot.

Try this sample code

a [sample app](https://github.com/lithium3141/BootLaunch) seems to confirm this behavior.

Comment: This is for VOIP-enabled app, and please make sure to put reference to the Author. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300992/1262634